# Flipping the View horizontally - How?

Tags: java, 3d, java-3d, off-screen, canvas3d

Recently I've found that all of my scene objects are in left-handed coordinates, but Java 3D uses right-hand coordinates. There is a solution: flipping the scene Z-axis and reverting the triangles winding order. But this will be a horrible mess. It seems that if I can somehow flip the view horizontally it will do the job needed. How can I achieve this? Applying Transform3D somewhere, some kind of offscreen rendering or...?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the view by rotating it on the Z axis by 180 degrees. This is assuming your using a SimpleUniverse.

```
Transform3D transform = new Transform3D();
transform.rotZ(Math.PI);
transform.setTranslation(vector);
univ.getViewingPlatform().getViewPlatformTransform().setTransform(transform);
```